# Storing files in Azure SQLdatabase

Tags: vb.net, azure

I have a vb.net based application which references an Azure SQL Database, I have set up a storage account to which I would like to store files to from the application.  I am not sure how to create that link between the DB and the Storage account?

Going through the "SQL Server Data Files in Windows Azure Storage service" Tutorial I cannot create a URI for the sotrage blob.  Using Azure Storage Explorer I select my container go into security and generate a signature which all works fine.  When I test the URI with the "Test in Browser" button I get this error:

```
 <Error>
 <Code>AuthenticationFailed</Code>
 <Message>
 Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature. RequestId:22ab2830-0001-001d-67a0-5460bb000000 Time:2014-10-17T14:06:11.9864269Z
 </Message>
 <AuthenticationErrorDetail>
 Signature did not match. String to sign used was r 2014-10-17T06:00:00Z 2014-10-25T06:00:00Z /macrocitrus/$root 2014-02-14
 </AuthenticationErrorDetail>
 </Error>
```

to what this means I have no idea.  I am a completely new user with Windows Azure so I am not even sure that I am on the right track?

Is there any documentation that actually explains the steps or what one would require to allow storage access from an SQL DB to an Azure Storage account?

Comment: Can you describe what exactly are you trying to accomplish? It is not very clear from the question. I know the answer to the error you're getting but I will wait for more details from you so that I can (hopefully) provide just one answer.

Comment: My apologies, I am wondering how to store files in the database from my application.  I want users to be able to download files, excel spread sheets etc.. edit them then re-save them back to the DB in specific locations.  I have the Database up and everything works with my application, but now I need to be able to upload and download files as well.  Is the storage account the correct answer? How can I incorporate this into my vb.net application?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would not recommend saving the binary content in SQL Database. Instead I would recommend that you save them in blob storage. Here are my reasons for doing so:

- Blob storage is designed for that purpose.
- Storing data in blob storage is much-much cheaper than storing the data in SQL Database.
- By storing binary data with other data, you're unnecessarily making your data access layer bulkier as all the data will be streamed through your database.

General approach in these kinds of scenarios is to keep binary data in blob storage as blobs (think of blobs as files in the cloud). Since each blob gets a unique URL, you can just store the URL in your SQL Database table. So if we go with this approach, what you will be doing is first uploading the blob in blob storage, get its URL and then update the database.

If you search for uploading files in blob storage, I am sure you will find a lot of examples with source code (so I will not bother providing it here :); I hope its all right).

Now coming to the error you're getting. Basically the link you created using Azure Storage Explorer is known as `Shared Access Signature (SAS) URL` which basically grants a time-limited/permission bound access to your storage account. Now Azure Storage Explorer gave you a SAS URL for the container. There are two ways you can use that URL (assuming you granted `Read` & `List` permissions when creating the SAS URL:

- To list blobs in that container, just append `restype=container&comp=list` to your URL and then paste it in the browser and you will see an XML listing of all blobs.
- To download a blob, you would need to insert the name of the blob in the URL. So if your URL is like `https://[youraccount].blob.core.windows.net/[yourcontainer]?[somestuffhere]` and your blob name is `myawesomepicture.png`, your SAS URL for viewing the file in the browser would be `https://[youraccount].blob.core.windows.net/[yourcontainer]/myawesomepicture.png?[somestuffhere]`

I wrote a blog post on using Shared Access Signatures which you may find useful: http://gauravmantri.com/2013/02/13/revisiting-windows-azure-shared-access-signature/.

Comment: Awesome thanks so much for this information!  Now I have some direction :)